# $http/Restangular 'GET' request returns error in Android version kitkat

Tags: android, angularjs, android-4.4-kitkat, restangular

I am trying to make a Web API request using **$http**, but it returns me a **status code of -1**, an error response after making the request. This happens only in the release build version of the app. If I run the app in the Debug version I can make a Web request.

The same issue I will face if I use Restangular to make Web request.

I created a sample cordova project and below is the code for it

```
(function () {
var app = angular.module('testApp', []);
})();

(function () {
"use strict";

var app = angular.module('testApp', []);

app.controller("testCtrl", [ '$http', function ($http) {
    alert("test Request");
    var validatePromise = $http({
        method: 'GET', url: 'https://SampleURL.list'
    });

    validatePromise.then(function (success) {
        alert("success");
    }, function (error) {
        alert("error");
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    });
}]);


} )();
```

Below is the Html code

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="default-src * 'self'
      'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' http://* https://* data: cdvfile://* content://*;">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">

<link href="css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="scripts/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>

<script src="scripts/index.js"></script>

<title>BlankCordovaApp3</title>
</head>
    <body ng-controller="testCtrl">
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive nav-title-slide-ios7" align 
title="center">
            <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon ion-arrow-left-c">
            </ion-nav-back-button>
        </ion-nav-bar>


            <!-- The title of the ion-view will be shown on the navbar -->
            <ion-view title="Page 1" hide-back-button="true">
                <ion-content class="padding">
                    <button class="button">
                        Default
                    </button>
                </ion-content>
            </ion-view>


</body>
```

**This issue I get only in the Release build and for Android Version below 4.4 (Kitkat)**

Comment: A status of `-1` often indicates a CORS problem.

Comment: @georgeawg I have added CORS related meta tag in index.html file, but still I get the same error. In the above html code I have included the Content-Security-Policy meta tag. I am missing something ?

Comment: Also this issue I get only in Android kitkat version. All above version works perfect.